# Specifying eclipse version in plugin.xml file

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to use an eclipse plugin having its source code.
I have tried to import it in eclipse Neon, the project gives no error but the jar doesn't work.
Then I have found in the "plugin.xml" file in the plugin project the line at the top `<?eclipse version="3.4"?>` which specifies the eclipse version so I installed eclipse version 3.4 and some errors appears.
My question is does this line means that the plugin won't work except on the eclipse version 3.4 and this is the reason for it not working on a newer version of eclipse.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The version at the top of the plugin.xml specifies the minimum version of Eclipse required by the plugin.xml specification. Any later version of Eclipse is OK as far as the plugin.xml is concerned. Currently 3.4 is still used for plugin.xml files created by any later version of Eclipse. So, no, this is not a reason that the plugin would not work on later versions of Eclipse.

The `Require-Bundle` and `Import-Package` statements in the MANIFEST.MF can specify in much more detail what versions of the various Eclipse plugins are required. Mismatches in these statements are much more likely to be a reason for the plugin not working.

If a plugin is not running always look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory as there is often a detailed message about what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Regarding the mismatch, in the ```Require-Bundle``` statrement there is "org.eclipse.core.expressions;bundle-version="3.4.300" " but the one in the library of the project "Plugin-Dependencies" is of version "3.5.1" but there is no error about mismatch, so are they compatable with each other?

Comment: That is ok, a single version number specifies the minimum version required. Two numbers are used to specify a valid range of versions (something like "[3.4.0,4.0.0)" for at least 3.4.0 and less than 4.0.0)